# ProgressBar between to activities in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

when click the grid item, i want to show a progressbar between the time of next Activity shown. then the second activity has a custom listview. there also i want to show a progressbar. how to do that?

Comment: What is happening to cause a delay that requires a progress bar?

Comment: when i run the program in the emulator, shows the black screen with my app_name in between the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just learning myself and I haven't had a chance to inspect the source, but I know that the [RedditIsFun](http://github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun) app (for [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/), of course) does this in-between loading the next links, and loading comments.  Check out the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

First Create the ProgressDilog in Activity. . .

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Now, Set the ProgressDialog in the Any action where u want to Take Some time

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FoodDriveModule.this, "", "Loading...");
```

Now use Thread to Handle the Progressbar

```
new Thread() 
   {
    public void run() 
    {
    try
    {
     sleep(1500);
// Now Do some Task whatever u want to do
   } 
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
   }
}.start();
```

Thats it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: And when will dissapear progressbar?